# Ajax jquery no me envía una imagen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola tengo un formulario y un `input` de tipo `file`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la imagen se envíe?

```
$( "#guardarDatos" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "core/modal/agregar.php",
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#datos_ajax_register").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#datos_ajax_register").html(datos);

                    load(1);
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault();
        });
```

el form

```
<div class="form-group">
            <h4 class="example-title">Subir Imagen</h4>
            <input type="file"  name="image">
      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="continente0" class="control-label">Author:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="continente0" name="author" value="<?php echo Session::get('username'); ?>"  required maxlength="15">
          </div>
```

Comment: En vez de serialize() intentaste con var parametros = new FormData($(this)) ?

Comment: Bien ahora los datos me los manda a la url

Comment: te funcionó la respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23895/822 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, primero lo que hay en el front-end:

```
$('#guardarDatos').submit(function( event ) {
  //obtenemos la imagen
  var imgElem = document.getElementById('image');
  //con esto generamos el texto de base64
  var imgData = getBase64Image(imgElem);
  //Creamos un input hidden y le asignamos ese texto generado
  var imagenNinja = document.createElement("input");
  imagenNinja.value = imgData;
  imagenNinja.name = "imagenBase64";
  imagenNinja.id = "imagenBase64";
  //con esto lo volvemos ninja para que nadie lo vea:
  imagenNinja.type = "hidden";
  var archivo = document.getElementById('image').parentNode.appendChild(imagenNinja);
  //ahora estos parametros van a tener la cadena de texto de Base 64 que representa la imagen
  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'core/modal/agregar.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: parametros,
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function(objeto){
         $("#datos_ajax_register").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
      },
      success: function(datos) {
         $("#datos_ajax_register").html(datos);
         load(1);
      }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});

function getBase64Image(imgElem) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Ahora en el backend de `PHP`

```
$data = $_POST['imagenBase64'];
//en la linea anterior se traduce como:
//$data = 'data:image/png;base64,AFFAAFdsgBLKLKS346fj42Pj4...';
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data); // ojo, aquí solamente revisamos por png, queda para que investigues cómo ver si aceptamos también jpg ;)
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$file = 'images/'. uniqid() . '.png'; // en lugar de uniqid() le pones el nombre que gustes :D
// guardamos el archivo
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```